# Redirect audio from laptop to desktop over LAN

Tags: windows-xp, audio, lan, input-director

I want to be able to play a song on my laptop and have it sound through my desktop's (infinitely better) speakers.

If you're familiar with [Input Director](http://www.inputdirector.com/): I want something that is to audio what Input Director is to mouse/keyboard. I want something that automatically redirects all audio from the laptop to the desktop in real time, *and* I want that solution to require, like Input Director, minimum maintenance. Beyond the initial setup, I don't want to have to babysit the program that does this. I want something that launches automatically with Windows and just works, and also allows me to cancel it whenever I want. And also doesn't go crazy when the laptop is turned on in a different network where the desktop computer isn't available.

Any suggestions for such a program?

(I use Windows XP on both computers.)

Comment: [Stardock Acoustic Bridge](http://www.stardock.com/products/acousticbridge/) only works with Windows Vista or later. :-(

Comment: You will find that there is lots of latency when doing this. So films and games wont be suitable. This should be OK for music though

Comment: A great solution is provided here: http://sound.stackexchange.com/a/35826/15198

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One software solution uses the free [VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) for streaming audio/video between computers.
For details see : [How-To: Stream almost anything using VLC](http://www.engadget.com/2005/11/29/how-to-stream-almost-anything-using-vlc/).

Another solution uses the Windows Media Player, but may possibly not apply to XP.
See this article: [Stream Music Over Your Home Network with Windows Media Player 12](http://www.7tutorials.com/stream-music-over-your-home-network-windows-media-player-12).

For completeness I mention  [Speakershare](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Audio/Other-AUDIO-Tools/Speakershare.shtml), although the project has disappeared from
[Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/speakershare/).
For more info see : [SpeakerShare Streams Music Between PCs with Minimal Fuss](http://lifehacker.com/5442578/speakershare-streams-music-between-pcs-with-minimal-fuss).

More software:

[PulseAudio](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio)
[Sound over RDP](http://www.fabulatech.com/sound-over-rdp.html) ($49, trial available)
[Virtual Audio Streaming](http://www.virtualaudiostreaming.net/) ($29.95, trial available)

Even more software, discussed in [this thread](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=50338):

[Axia IP-Audio Driver for Windows](http://axiaaudio.com/system-components/#Driver)
[Jamcast](http://www.sdstechnologies.com/) ($29.99, trial available)
[Sharing Media Over The Internet Using foobar2000](http://www.sdstechnologies.com/Wiki/Sharing-Media-Over-The-Internet-Using-foobar2000.ashx)

Comment: None of the 3 solutions you propose will work for me: 1. The VLC solution is for streaming specific files, while I'm interested in streaming all audio from all applications. 2. The Windows Media Player 12 solution would not work on my XP systems. 3. Regarding SpeakerShare, I prefer to avoid abandonware.

Comment: I added some more software products.

Comment: None of the new 3 solutions you proposes worked for me: 1. PulseAudio is not friendly for non-Linux-nerds. (The Windows builds don't include an installer, are of an old version, and there's no explanation on how to use it.) 2. I tried Sound over RDP, but it requires keeping Microsoft's Remote Desktop open, which is way more clutter than I want to tolerate. 3. I tried Virtual Audio Streaming, but it didn't work.

Comment: I added even more software to check out.

Comment: Actually, VLC doesn't only stream specific files. It can be used to stream a video and/or audio mix (i.e. everything on the screen + everything coming from the sound card) directly from a PC to any wireless device. I don't have the specifics, but I'm planning on trying this myself over the weekend.

Comment: Another thing that I find unattractive about using VLC for this purpose is that it's a media player, and as far as I know not intended to be run in the background like this. (I'd love to be proven wrong on this.) For example, will it have to stay open all the time with an entry in the task bar? What happens if I actually want to use VLC to play a movie?

Comment: For the taskbar, there are products that minimize programs to the traybar.

Comment: VLC is not only a media player. It also provides an excellent streaming media server that can be used without the GUI. In this role, it's completely intended to be run in the background. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player for more details, and then hit up the VideoLAN site: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html for more detiled documentation.

Comment: VLC can redirect the speakers if their driver supports it. If not, you will need the commercial [Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm) (trial available) for connecting the speakers to VLC. VLC can be invoked via command-line parameters and no GUI. [This article](http://wiki.serviio.org/doku.php?id=stream_pc) describes how one guy managed it and could be adapted to your case.